# PopUp Bootstrap Modal on asp:RadioButtonList Click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap5-modal

I have to add a functionality when I click on the asp:ListItem Value="S" on the Asp:radiobuttonlist then bootstrap modal will popup.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoPanYesNoSearch" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdoPanYesNoSearch_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Y">&lt;span style=&quot;color:Green;font-size:15px;&quot;&gt;Yes&lt;/span&gt;</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="N">&lt;span style=&quot;color:Green;font-size:15px;&quot;&gt;No&lt;/span&gt;</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="S" CssClass="btnShow">Search</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I have added the same functionality using button but my current requirement is for a radio button list.

Front End:

```
<button id="btnShow" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Modal</button>
    
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="testModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Search Customer</h5>    
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Customer Name " Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerNameModal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text=" OR PAN No." Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPANNoModal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnShowList" runat="server" Text="Show List" CssClass="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <asp:Button ID="btnClearModal" runat="server" Text="Clear" CssClass="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
        const container = document.getElementById("testModal");
        const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(container);

        document.getElementById("btnShow").addEventListener("click", function () {
            modal.show();
        });
</script>
```

Above code have that functionality if I click on button then modal will popup.

Help would be really appreciated.

I want whenever I click on Search asp:ListItem then the same modal will get display on the screen as I have created for button.

Comment: Solution of this problem:

Instead of adding CssClass="btnShow". You can inspect the Asp:radiobuttonlist and check the ID, then you'll get ID something similar to this ContentPlaceHolder_BodyMain_rdoPanYesNoSearch_2. 
        document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder_BodyMain_rdoPanYesNoSearch_2").addEventListener("click", function () {
            modal.show();
        });